# Iterate using the correct method integerForKey, objectForKey for NSUserDefaults, to backup to a DB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to dump all the `NSUserDefaults` used in my app to m database.

Why ? Because, I'm creating backup / restore functionality, where I'm only backing up the database file. This way I can keep all the settings in my database. I guess I'll need to do it line by line using insert queries.

**You may well say, why don't you just store the values in your database to start with, we'll this would be a lot more work and impact performance. And is only a last resort option for me.**

My problem if that normally when I'm saving to `NSUserDefaults` I would use either `setInteger`, `setObject` but how can I determine what to use in a loop.

I know I can iterate like this...

```
NSUserDefaults * defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary * dict = [defs dictionaryRepresentation];
for (id key in dict) {
    [defs removeObjectForKey:key];
}
[defs synchronize];
```

I don't want to have to do a call for each of my Key.

EDIT

I've found this, which I could use to dump to one record in my DB, but I'm not sure how to pass it back ?

```
NSDictionary *bundleInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
  NSString *bundleId = [bundleInfo objectForKey: @"CFBundleIdentifier"];

  NSUserDefaults *appUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"Start dumping userDefaults for %@", bundleId);
  NSLog(@"userDefaults dump: %@", [appUserDefaults persistentDomainForName: 
         bundleId]);
  NSLog(@"Finished dumping userDefaults for %@", bundleId);
  [appUserDefaults release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe, you can create a dictionary with your app's settings using `-persistentDomainForName`. Then you have a simple `NSDictionary`.

You can create a string from a dictionary by converting it to an XML representation of a property list:

```
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList: dict format: NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options: 0 error: nil];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can store that in your DB. (You can also just store the data immediately)

You can then use `-propertyListWithData:options:format:error:` to convert that back into an NSDictionary:

```
NSString *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: data options: 0 format: NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 error: nil];
```

Then just loop through all the keys in that dictionary and use `-setObject:forKey` to write those elements back to the user defaults.

Comment: Looking good, will setObject cater for setInteger, I think this might be an issue, not at my mac right now to check.

Comment: Sure! `-setInteger:` is basically just a convenience wrapper for `-setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:xxx]`